# How to create a stacked area chart in R from a csv with non-numerical data

Tags: r

I am trying to create a stacked area chart in R using data from this csv: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/data/master/masculinity-survey/raw-responses.csv

(The above file is raw content, for better readability of the data look here: https://github.com/fivethirtyeight/data/blob/master/masculinity-survey/masculinity-survey.csv)

I am trying to create a percentage based stacked area chart, that i similar to this example: https://r-charts.com/en/evolution/percentage-stacked-area_files/figure-html/percentage-areaplot.png

The problem is that since i am working with non-numerical data only, it is a bit hard for me to get a proper graph.

My goal is to have the graph display the different age groups in the x-axis ( row "age3" in raw content), and the fill to be the ethnicities (row "racethn4" in raw content. All while the y axis simply is the percentage that represents the number of total answers in the survey (that of course goes up to 100).

I tried to do it the following way, but im not sure what the y value should be:

```
df <- read_csv("Path to csv")

ggplot(df, aes(x = df$age3, y = ???, fill = df$racethn4)) + geom_stream()
```

Any ideas on how to represent the plot as described?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not too well versed in ggplot as I use other graphing packages but I gave this a shot. I don't believe you can use `geom_area` when x is a categorical variable. At least I did not have any luck trying that. So I used `geom_col` instead.

Here's two approaches for transforming the data. Using `dplyr` and `data.table`. Feel free to pick whichever is more natural for you.

You need to sum up the number of observations per group combo first and then get the percent total for the y values.

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

dat = fread("temp.csv") # from data.table::fread

# data.table way
dat_sub = dat[, .(age3 = as.factor(age3), racethn4 = as.factor(racethn4))][,.N, by = .(age3,racethn4)]
dat_sub[, tot := sum(N), by = age3][, perc := N/tot*100][order(age3)]

# dplyr way
dat_sub = dat %>%
  select(age3, racethn4) %>%
  group_by(age3, racethn4) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  group_by(age3) %>%
  mutate(tot = sum(n),
         perc = n / tot * 100)

# using a stacked bar chart instead of stacked area
ggplot(dat_sub, aes(x = age3, y = perc, fill = racethn4)) + 
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: If you set `width = 1` inside `geom_col()`, it will eliminate the space between columns and look a bit more like a stacked area chart.